# Failed to execute 'open' invalid URL from WebStorm IDE while sending GET request using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, cors, webstorm

I enabled CORS module and set required options in my nodeJS server code. I am able to send the GET request from my browser to the given URL and getting response. But when I am trying to execute below code for sending a GET request using following AngularJS code from WebStorm IDE's built-in server I am getting below error.

```
city name Delhi
error SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
```

Code is as follows.

```
mainApp.controller('dController', function($scope,$http) {
    this.ccaid = {
        city:'',
        circle:'',
        area:'',
    };
    this.getCircle=function(){
        console.log('city name ' + this.ccaid.city);
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            crossDomain:true,
            url: 'xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/fetchCityArea',
            params:{city:this.ccaid.city}
        }).then(function(success){
            console.log('response ' + success);
        },function(error){
            console.log('error ' + error);
        });
    };
});
```

There is nothing wrong with the URL but still it is unable to send GET request.

How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your URL include a scheme? Your example code doesn’t:

```
url: 'xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/fetchCityArea',
```

That needs to have a scheme part—`http://` or `https://`:

```
url: 'https://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/fetchCityArea',
```

Comment: This issue was resolved for me when i tried to send get parameters as query string rather than using params property. also as mentioned by you i added the scheme part also to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sideshowbarker's answer -

The URLs should be of WHATWG URL Standard. 
Examples of valid URLs formats are here - https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#example-url-parsing

Answer (score -1):

The problem I encountered is that my URL IS invalid.

```
http://ip::8080/
```

There is an extra colon.
I may not be the only one.